# What is the minimal setup needed to write to HDFS/GS on Google Cloud Storage with flume?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, flume-ng, google-hadoop

I would like to write data from flume-ng  to Google Cloud Storage.
It is a little bit complicated, because I observed a very strange behavior. Let me explain:

## Introduction

I've launched a hadoop cluster on google cloud (one click) set up to use a bucket.

When I ssh on the master and add a file with `hdfs` command, I can see it immediately in my bucket

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /
14/11/27 15:01:41 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.2.9-hadoop2
Found 1 items
-rwx------   3 hadoop hadoop         40 2014-11-27 13:45 /test.txt
```

But when I try to add then read from my computer, it seems to use some other HDFS. Here I added a file called `jp.txt`, and it doesn't show my previous file `test.txt`

```
$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://ip.to.my.cluster/
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 jp supergroup          0 2014-11-27 14:57 hdfs://ip.to.my.cluster/jp.txt
```

That's also the only file I see when I explore HDFS on `http://ip.to.my.cluster:50070/explorer.html#/`

When I list files in my bucket with the web console (https://console.developers.google.com/project/my-project-id/storage/my-bucket/), I can only see `test.txt` and not `jp.txt`.

I read [Hadoop cannot connect to Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132011/hadoop-cannot-connect-to-google-cloud-storage) and I configured my hadoop client accordingly (pretty hard stuff) and now I can see items in my bucket. But for that, I need to use a `gs://` URI

```
$ hadoop fs -ls gs://my-bucket/
14/11/27 15:57:46 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.3.0-hadoop2
Found 1 items
-rwx------   3 jp jp         40 2014-11-27 14:45 gs://my-bucket/test.txt
```

## Observation / Intermediate conclusion

So it seems here there are 2 different storages engine in the same cluster: "traditional HDFS" (starting with `hdfs://`) and a Google storage bucket (starting with `gs://`).

Users and rights are different, depending on where you are listing files from.

## Question(s)

The main question is: What is the minimal setup needed to write to HDFS/GS on Google Cloud Storage with flume ?

### Related questions

- Do I need to launch a Hadoop cluster on Google Cloud or not to achieve my goal?
- Is it possible to write directly to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket ? If yes, how can I configure flume? (adding jars, redefining classpath...)
- How come there are 2 storage engine in the same cluster (classical HDFS / GS bucket)

### My flume configuration

```
a1.sources = http
a1.sinks = hdfs_sink
a1.channels = mem

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.http.type =  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
a1.sources.http.port = 9000

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://ip.to.my.cluster:8020/%{env}/%{tenant}/%{type}/%y-%m-%d
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.filePrefix = %H-%M-%S_
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .json
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.mem.type = memory
a1.channels.mem.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.mem.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.http.channels = mem
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.channel = mem
```

Does the line a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.path accept a `gs://` path ?

What setup would it need in that case (additional jars, classpath) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, it's actually fairly common to be able to access different storage systems from the same Hadoop cluster, based on the `scheme://` of the URI you use with `hadoop fs`. The cluster you deployed on Google Compute Engine also has both filesystems available, it just happens to have the "default" set to `gs://your-configbucket`.

The reason you had to include the `gs://configbucket/file` instead of just plain `/file` on your local cluster is that in your one-click deployment, we additionally included a key in your Hadoop's `core-site.xml`, setting `fs.default.name` to be `gs://configbucket/`. You can achieve the same effect on your local cluster to make it use GCS for all the schemeless paths; in your one-click cluster, check out `/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/core-site.xml` for a reference of what you might carry over to your local setup.

To explain the internals of Hadoop a bit, the reason `hdfs://` paths work normally is actually because there is a configuration key which in theory can be overridden in Hadoop's `core-site.xml` file, which by default sets:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>
  <description>The FileSystem for hdfs: uris.</description>
</property>
```

Similarly, you may have noticed that to get `gs://` to work on your local cluster, you provided `fs.gs.impl`. This is because DistribtedFileSystem and GoogleHadoopFileSystem both implement the same Hadoop Java interface `FileSystem`, and Hadoop is built to be agnostic to how an implementation chooses to actually implement the FileSystem methods. This also means that at the most basic level, anywhere you could normally use `hdfs://` you should be able to use `gs://`.

So, to answer your questions:

1. The same minimal setup you'd use to get Flume working with a typical HDFS-based setup should work for using GCS as a sink.
2. You don't need to launch the cluster on Google Compute Engine, though it'd be easier, as you experienced with the more difficult manual instructions for using the GCS connector on your local setup. But since you already have a local setup running, it's up to you whether Google Compute Engine will be an easier place to run your Hadoop/Flume cluster.
3. Yes, as mentioned above, you should experiment with replacing `hdfs://` paths with `gs://` paths instead, and/or setting `fs.default.name` to be your root `gs://configbucket` path.
4. Having the two storage engines allows you to more easily switch between the two in case of incompatibilities. There are some minor differences in supported features, for example GCS won't have the same kinds of posix-style permissions you have in HDFS. Also, it doesn't support `appends` to existing files or symlinks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought that using `gs://` or `hdfs://` would result in the same behaviour (except for GS limitations you mentionned). I thought that 'one click cluster' would result in an abstraction for storage, but in fact files are stored in different places (GS bucket and hard drives of cluster nodes). I expected to see the same files, either with `gs://` or `hdfs://`

Comment: Now it seems to work: folders and files are created accordingly to the pattern I wrote, but files are empty and I have a Java heap space in GCS code: http://pastebin.com/i5iSgCM3 / https://gist.github.com/jpcaruana/3a960ff64ff0eb1c30e0 . Any idea ?

Comment: Since the GCS connector is optimized for large-scale workloads which typically average at least several hundred megabytes per file, file-creation by default initializes a fairly large 64MB in-memory default at the time of file-creation. This setting is controlled by fs.gs.io.buffersize.write (default 67108864) which you can try to alter to a smaller number (perhaps 8388608) inside your core-site.xml. Alternatively, simply make sure wherever you're able to pass in jvm flags, to include something like -Xmx2048m to increase the max heap size.

Comment: thanks Dennis ; I asked the question elsewhere : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232966/what-causes-flume-with-gcs-sink-to-throw-a-outofmemoryexception and had a similar answer.