# What causes flume with GCS sink to throw a OutOfMemoryException

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, flume-ng, google-hadoop

I am using flume to write to Google Cloud Storage. Flume listens on `HTTP:9000`. It took me some time to make it work (add gcs libaries, use a credentials file...) but now it seems to communicate over the network.

I am sending very small HTTP request for my tests, and I have plenty of RAM available:

```
curl -X POST -d '[{ "headers" : { timestamp=1417444588182, env=dev, tenant=myTenant, type=myType }, "body" : "some body ONE"  }]' localhost:9000
```

I encounter this memory exception on first request (then of course, it stops working):

```
2014-11-28 16:59:47,748 (hdfs-hdfs_sink-call-runner-0) [INFO - com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.LogUtil.info(LogUtil.java:142)] GHFS version: 1.3.0-hadoop2
2014-11-28 16:59:50,014 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:467)] process failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.<init>(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.<init>(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:79)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.create(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:820)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
```

(see [complete stack trace as a gist](https://gist.github.com/jpcaruana/3a960ff64ff0eb1c30e0) for full details)

The strange part is that folders and files are created the way I want, but files are empty.

```
gs://my_bucket/dev/myTenant/myType/2014-12-01/14-36-28.1417445234193.json.tmp
```

Is it something wrong with the way I configured flume + GCS or is it a bug in [GCS.jar](https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar) ?

Where should I check to gather more data ?

ps : I am running flume-ng inside docker.

---

My `flume.conf` file:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = http
a1.sinks = hdfs_sink
a1.channels = mem

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.http.type =  org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
a1.sources.http.port = 9000

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.path = gs://my_bucket/%{env}/%{tenant}/%{type}/%Y-%m-%d
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.filePrefix = %H-%M-%S
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .json
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.mem.type = memory
a1.channels.mem.capacity = 10000
a1.channels.mem.transactionCapacity = 1000

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.http.channels = mem
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.channel = mem
```

---

related question in my flume/gcs journey: [What is the minimal setup needed to write to HDFS/GS on Google Cloud Storage with flume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174033/what-is-the-minimal-setup-needed-to-write-to-hdfs-gs-on-google-cloud-storage-wit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When uploading files, the GCS Hadoop FileSystem implementation sets aside a fairly large (64MB) write buffer per FSDataOutputStream (file open for write). This can be changed by setting ["fs.gs.io.buffersize.write"](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/fs/gcs/GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java#L120) to a smaller value, in bytes, in core-site.xml. I imagine 1MB would suffice for low-volume log collection.

In addition, check what the maximum heap size is set to when launching the JVM for flume. The flume-ng script sets a default JAVA_OPTS value of -Xmx20m to limit the heap to 20MB. This can be set to a larger value in flume-env.sh (see conf/flume-env.sh.template in the flume tarball distribution for details).

Comment: too bad we cannot pass the JVM size to flume-ng