# Connect hadoop cluster to mutiple Google Cloud Storage backets in multiple Google Projects

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-hadoop

It is possible, to connect my Hadoop cluster to multiple Google Cloud Projects at once ?

I can easly use any Google Storage bucket in single Google Project via Google Cloud Storage Connector as explained in this thread [Migrating 50TB data from local Hadoop cluster to Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291397/migrating-50tb-data-from-local-hadoop-cluster-to-google-cloud-storage). But i can't find any documentation or example how to connect to two or more Google Cloud Project from single map-reduce job. Do You have any suggestion/trick ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is possible to connect your cluster to buckets from multiple different projects at once. Ultimately, if you're using the instructions for [using a service-account keyfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291397/migrating-50tb-data-from-local-hadoop-cluster-to-google-cloud-storage), the GCS requests are performed on behalf of that service-account, which can be treated more-or-less like any other user. You can either add the service account email `your-service-account-email@developer.gserviceaccount.com` to all the different cloud projects owning buckets you want to process, using the `permissions` section of cloud.google.com/console and simply adding that email address like any other member, or you can set [GCS-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-examples) to add that service-account like any other user.