# How to enable hadoop access to Google Cloud using .boto file

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage

Our company is migrating from s3 to GCS. While the command-line utility `gsutil` works fine, I am facing difficulty in configuring Hadoop (core-site.xml) to enable access to GCS. This google page https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-conf/gcs-core-default.xml lists the name-value pairs that need to be added, but I don't find any of these in the ~/.boto file. The .boto file only has the following set:

1. `gs_oauth2_refresh_token` under [Credentials]
2. default_project_id under [GSUtil]
3. Few others like api_version etc..
   The [OAuth2] section is empty.

Can I somehow generate the necessary keys using `gs_oauth2_refresh_token` and add them to Hadoop config? Or can I get these from any other `gsutil` config files?

Answer (score 0):

For hadoop configuration you'll likely want to use a service-account rather than gsutil credentials that are associated with an actual email address; see [these instructions for manual installation of the GCS connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291397/migrating-50tb-data-from-local-hadoop-cluster-to-google-cloud-storage/25342520#25342520) for more details about setting up a `p12` keyfile along with the other necessary configuration parameters.