# Can Hive load data from external location which is not on HDFS?

Tags: hive, hdfs, google-cloud-storage, remote-access, hive-partitions

I am trying to understand that for the external table in Hive, can we have the location outside of HDFS, I mean is that I want to create my external table on top of Google storage location (gs://bucket-name/table-partitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a difficult problem but requires out-of-box provisioning, something which isn't particularly well documented over Google Cloud. In order to fix it, update the following Hadoop configurations parameter:

A. Point your service account key string to that of google service account (ex: domains include @test.gservice.com) for google.cloud.auth.service.account.email.

B. Update the keyfile string to the .p12 location for google.cloud.auth.service.account.keyfile.

C. Update google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable to true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution is of particular help.

Comment: I am excited that it is of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

I want to update on my previously asked question that yes, it's possible with almost no code change on Google DataProc cluster or on a standalone cluster, you can follow on this link - [Migrating 50TB data from local Hadoop cluster to Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291397/migrating-50tb-data-from-local-hadoop-cluster-to-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: Yes, but that only partly solves your issue based on the recent changes for AWS and Google Cloud.