# Copy Data from Google Cloud Storage into Local Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to copy data from a Bucket in Google Cloud Storage into Local Hadoop Cluster(Which I have installed in my Mac). Have followed the instructions as given in this link ; [Migrating 50TB data from local Hadoop cluster to Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291397/migrating-50tb-data-from-local-hadoop-cluster-to-google-cloud-storage/25342520#25342520)
But I am getting the following error when I execute the hdfs command `hdfs dfs -ls gs://tempuserstorage`.

```
17/04/28 15:42:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/28 15:42:14 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.6.0-hadoop2
    -ls: Google Cloud Storage bucket name must not contain '/' character.
    Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]
```

I have also tried `hadoop fs -ls gs://tempuserstorage` but getting the same error though

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have made a mistake while provide value for `fs.gs.system.bucket`. Apart for the bucket name(say `mybucket`) ; I have also added the directory inside the bucket(`mybucket/mydir`) which seems to have caused the problem